# Viima JQuery Comments - GetUsers(Pinged users) displaying incorrectly in partialview

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, json

### References

- [jquery comments](https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments)
- The [jquery comments documentation](http://viima.github.io/jquery-comments/)
- [this issue in github](https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments/issues/147)

### Attachments

- `comments-data.js` is test data : [Download here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cyiUGLu0Q32FRk8oX9lWgWy6ZAcUGuti)
- `jquery-comments.js` creates the whole comments system: [Download here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-I-NW0rGUiroD8SeQXBuRB8ZlS-h9rfo)
- `jquery-comments.min.js` if you require it: [Download here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xGEz7lJej9lIp7LkzpT0lVvgKA4Uk6Cp)

### Description

I have a view with a list of "articles" with a "read more" button on each "article" in the list. When I click on the read more button a modal opens up with a partial view with the jquery comments in it. However, when I search for the pinged users (using the `@` sign), the list of users don't show by the `textarea`, but instead higher up in the modal (far from the `textarea`).

Below is an image, then below that is my code. You will see at the bottom of the image I have put the '@' sign and the list of users is displayed on the top, it should be by the `textarea`. It also seems that when I click on the articles lower in the list, the higher the list of users display when I push the '@' sign:

[image]

### MVC View

Below is the part populating the "Articles" from where the Modal is being called from:

```
@{
    int iGroupNameId = 0;
    int iTotalArticles = 0;
    foreach (var groupItems in Model.ArticleGroups)
    {
        iTotalArticles = Model.ArticlesList.Where(x => x.fkiGroupNameId == groupItems.pkiKnowledgeSharingCenterGroupsId).Count();
        if (iTotalArticles > 0)
        {
            <div style="background: linear-gradient(#B5012E, darkred); margin: 10px; padding: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: white; text-transform: uppercase;">@groupItems.GroupName</div><div class="container" style="width:100%">
                @if (groupItems.pkiKnowledgeSharingCenterGroupsId != iGroupNameId)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.ArticlesList.Where(x => x.fkiGroupNameId == groupItems.pkiKnowledgeSharingCenterGroupsId))
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                                {
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                <i class="fa fa-gear"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="@Url.Action("EditArticle", "ILearn", new { id = item.KnowledgeSharingArticlesId })">Edit</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteArticle", "ILearn", new { id = item.KnowledgeSharingArticlesId })">Delete</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                }

                                <img src="@item.ArticleImage" class="img-responsive" alt="img" style="width:350px;height:200px">
                                <ul class="list-inline padding-10">
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        @item.DateTimeStamp.ToLongDateString()
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                                        @item.ArticleComments
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                                        @item.ArticleViews
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 padding-left-0">
                                <h6 class="margin-top-0"> <span style="font-size:large">@item.Title</span><br><small class="font-xs"><i>Published by <a href="@Url.Action("GetProfileData","UserProfile", new { userid = item.fkiUserId })">@item.User_FullName</a></i></small></h6>
                                <p>
                                    @Html.Raw(item.Description)
                                </p>
                                @*<a class="btn btn-danger" href="@Url.Action("ShowArticleDetails", "ILearn", new { id = item.KnowledgeSharingArticlesId })">Read more</a>*@
                                <button type="button" onclick="showArticle('@item.KnowledgeSharingArticlesId')" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#show-details-modal" data-toggle="modal">
                                    Read more
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        }

    }
}
```

### Modal

This is placed at the top of the page(Under the @model appname.ViewModels.VM):

```
<!--Loading Panel-->
<div id="loadingPanel" style="display: none;">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 100%">...LOADING...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Show details modal-->
<div id="show-details-modal" class="modal fade" style="width:100%">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                <div id="loadingPanelShowDetails" class="col-md-12 text-center" style="display: none;">
                    <br />
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 100%">...LOADING...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="target-show-details">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Jquery Code

```
function showArticle(id) {
$("#target-show-details").html('');
$('#loadingPanelShowDetails').show();
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '@Url.Action("ShowArticleDetails", "ILearn")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { "id": id },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#target-show-details").html(result);
        $('#loadingPanelShowDetails').hide();

        var saveComment = function (data) {
            $(data.pings).each(function (index, id) {
                var user = usersArray.filter(function (user) { return user.id == id })[0];
                alert(user.fullname);
                data.content = data.content.replace('@@' + id, '@@' + user.fullname);
            });

            return data;
        }
        $('#articlecomments-container').comments({
            profilePictureURL: 'https://viima-app.s3.amazonaws.com/media/public/defaults/user-icon.png',
            currentUserId: 1,
            roundProfilePictures: true,
            textareaRows: 1,
            enableAttachments: true,
            enableHashtags: true,
            enablePinging: true,
            getUsers: function (success, error) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    traditional: true,
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetPinnedUsers", "ILearn")',
                    success: function (usersArray) {
                        success(usersArray)
                    },
                    error: error
                });
            },
            getComments: function (success, error) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { "id": id },
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetArticleComments", "ILearn")',
                    success: function (commentsArray) {
                        success(saveComment(commentsArray))
                    },
                    error: error
                });
            },
            postComment: function (data, success, error) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '@Url.Action("PostArticleComment", "ILearn")',
                    data: { "CVM": data, "articleId": id },
                    success: function (comment) {
                        success(comment);
                    },
                    error: error
                });
            },
            putComment: function (data, success, error) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '@Url.Action("PutArticleComment", "ILearn")',
                    data: { "CVM": data, "articleId": id },
                    success: function (comment) {
                        success(comment);
                    },
                    error: error
                });
            },
            deleteComment: function (data, success, error) {
                $.SmartMessageBox({
                    title: "Deleting Comment?",
                    content: "Are you sure that you want to delete this comment?",
                    buttons: '[No][Yes]'
                }, function (ButtonPressed) {
                    if (ButtonPressed === "Yes") {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteArticleComment", "ILearn")',
                            data: { "CVM": data, "articleId": id },
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.status === "usersuccess") {
                                    $.smallBox({
                                        title: "<strong>Comment Deleted</strong>",
                                        content: "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>Comment was successfully deleted! <strong</strong></i>",
                                        color: "#659265",
                                        iconSmall: "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                                        timeout: 4000
                                    });
                                    success();
                                } else {
                                    success();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (ButtonPressed === "No") {
                        $.smallBox({
                            title: "<strong>Comment not deleted</strong>",
                            content: "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>This comment has not been deleted.</i>",
                            color: "#C46A69",
                            iconSmall: "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                            timeout: 4000
                        });
                    }

                });
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            upvoteComment: function (data, success, error) {
                if (data.user_has_upvoted) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: '@Url.Action("UpVoteArticleComment", "ILearn")',
                        data: { "CVM": data, "articleId": id },
                        success: function () {
                            success(data)
                        },
                        error: error
                    });
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteArticleCommentUpvote", "ILearn")',
                        data: { "commentId": data.id },
                        success: function () {
                            success(commentJSON)
                        },
                        error: error
                    });
                }
            },
            uploadAttachments: function (commentArray, success, error) {
                var responses = 0;
                var successfulUploads = [];

                var serverResponded = function () {
                    responses++;

                    // Check if all requests have finished
                    if (responses == commentArray.length) {

                        // Case: all failed
                        if (successfulUploads.length == 0) {
                            error();

                            // Case: some succeeded
                        } else {
                            success(successfulUploads)
                        }
                    }
                }

                $(commentArray).each(function (index, commentJSON) {

                    // Create form data
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    $(Object.keys(commentJSON)).each(function (index, key) {
                        var value = commentJSON[key];
                        if (value) formData.append(key, value);
                    });

                    formData.append('fkiKnowledgeSharingArticlesId', id);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("UploadToArticleComments", "ILearn")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (commentJSON) {
                            successfulUploads.push(commentJSON);
                            serverResponded();
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            serverResponded();
                        },
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
}
```

### MVC Partial View

```
@model Innovation_Cafe.Models.KnowledgeSharingArticles
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="margin-top-10">
        <div style="text-align:center;border:solid;border-style:solid">
            <img src="@Model.ArticleImage" class="img-responsive" alt="img" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
        <ul class="list-inline padding-10">
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                @Model.DateTimeStamp.ToLongDateString()
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                @Model.ArticleComments
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                @Model.ArticleViews
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h6 class="margin-top-0"> @Model.Title<br><small class="font-xs"><i>Published by <a href="@Url.Action(" GetProfileData","UserProfile", new { userid=Model.fkiUserId })">@Model.User_FullName</a></i></small></h6>
    <br />
    <p>
        @Html.Raw(Model.Description)
    </p>
    <p>
        @if (Model.FileType == ".mp4")
            {
            <div style="text-align:center;border-style:solid">
                <video controls width="100%">
                    <source src="@Model.FilePath" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            if (Model.FilePath !=null)
            {
            <p>Click here to view file: <a href="@Model.FilePath" target="_blank">Click here</a></p>
            }
        }

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <hr style="border:solid" />
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="articlecomments-container">

        </div>
    </div>
```

At the bottom of the partial view is this div where it is populated:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="articlecomments-container">

    </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

After spending quite some time running through the `jquery-comments.js` file, I found that displaying of the pinged users its happening here:

```
 // CUSTOM CODE
 // ========================================================================================================================================================================================
 // Adjust vertical position
    var top = parseInt(this.$el.css('top')) + self.options.scrollContainer.scrollTop();
    this.$el.css('top', top);
```

This seems to be taking the css('top') of View, which causes the problem on the pinging of the users on the partialview.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddlel link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue takes place rather because of your wrong bootstrap layout: you have to include all `col` into `row`, whereas in your example you use `raw` and `col-md-12` for the same container.

After I included columns into `row` elements correctly everything started working the right way. In other words, just write the last section this way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="articlecomments-container">

    </div>
</div>
```

Please, take a look at an example of [nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#nesting) in Bootstrap 4.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to reproduce the mistake thanks to your tip to draw numerous articles on the page. The issue is indeed because of scrolling, though the reason seems to be deeper in `jquery.textcomplete.js` in a function `_fitToBottom` (it takes into account the main window scroll but not of the embeded modal container). However, a faster approach I use instead of rectifying that elaborate peice of logic is exactly at the spot which you pointed to (instead of the last 2 rows you showed):

```
var topPoint = self.options.scrollContainer[0].offsetTop;
var scrolledWindow = self.options.scrollContainer.parents().filter(function () {
    return this.scrollTop > 0;
})[0];
var spaceAvailable = $(window).height() - (topPoint - scrolledWindow.scrollTop);

var elHeight = this.$el.height();
this.$el.css('top', spaceAvailable > elHeight ? topPoint: topPoint - elHeight);
```

The logic is based on looking for the closest parent with scroll and then it measures whether the rest of the space is enough to render the dropdown to figure out its final position. It might slightly miss the pointer, but still works fine in spite of scrolling. I've tried it out in Chrome and Firefox. Hopefully, it will lead you to your own approach.

Comment: Your browser might also affect the behaviour: whereas the layout I described above works in Chrome, it's rendered wrongly in IE.

Comment: I made the change but the same thing is happening. I ran through the .js file that populates the whole commenting system and found the code where the pinned users are being "populated". It seems to be the scrolling of the view that is making it be positioned incorrectly(it seems to be looking at the views .css("Top"). I have no idea to make it find where the textarea is and populate it there... I wanted to post the  .js file, but its too big, it wont let me.

Comment: Are you sure you've shared all the code of PartialView? Could you reveal the place where you open the modal?

Comment: Done. I have added the Modal and explained where it is placed on the View, as well as updated the JQuery Code.

Comment: Thanks. In effect, it hasn't cleared up the reason. So, I assembled everything into a tiny [demo application](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4DXB/uK8dWVQ1h) inspired with your code and the jquery-official demo (couldn't publish it on jsfiddle and the link leads to a Russian portal where you should click a blue button to download). Whenever one writes `<div class="row col-md-12">` instead of `<div class="row">` for the parent of `<div id="comments-container">` they runs into the problem you depicted.

Comment: Thus, I'd recommend you to simplify your layout at first to make everything right and then gradually build your application around it until it gets broken. You might as well have a look at the complete code of your page (instead of different parts published here) and find the mistake in your layout there. By the way, in what browsers do you run into the flaw?

Comment: I completely understand. I would have put in a jsfiddle, but it wouldnt work unfortunately. So thanks for the suggestion. I will have a look at that and if it does work, I will let you know. I am running it in chrome.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, really appreciate the effort you went to, to create a demo. I gave it a go, but the same issue occurs when you add multiple "Articles" that requires you to scroll down, then the same issue occurs :(

Comment: You're welcome! According to the recent clues I've published one more approach which might be more helpful.

Comment: Oleg, that is spot on! It works! After the change, I needed to make the change on the div by removing the col-md-12 as you said as well. So once I changed the code as you provided and did the change as you specified right in the beginning of your post, it worked 100%! THANK YOU!!!! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Oleg, sorry to bug you, I please need your help on another issue related to the above solution please. I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077381/mvc-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-scrolltop-of-undefined-at-dropdo - I have used your demo from this solution and adapted it to give the error I am getting. If you can help, thanks a million!

Comment: Sure, @AxleWack, I'll strive to give it a galnce. However, it might take some time, since I'm having my hands full this week.

Comment: no worries dude, I eventually got it sorted! Thanks in any case for your complete willingness to help! You are 1 of the very few on SO that are really here to help! Cheers!